# Использование в коде классов, находящихся в разных файлах

Tags: php, phpstorm

При написании кода каждый класс писался в своём файле. Все файлы находятся в одном и том же пространстве имён. То есть, когда, допустим, объявляю новый экземпляр класса, то IDE выводит подсказки, то есть видит его. Однако, когда код запускается на исполнение,то выдаёт ошибку вида:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Moving' not found in D:\Homework\make.php:20
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in D:\Homework\make.php on line 20
```

make.php - запускаемый файл, в нём я пишу:

```
$m = new Moving("pam pam");
```

Comment: Классы то у Вас загружаются при исполнении? http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: @robertobadjo , большое спасибо. Комментарий решил проблему

Comment: Чтобы таких проблем не возникало, советую использовать composer